# SharePoint 2010 auto increment field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to create a workflow (I think this is the good way) to make a custom field which contains a company code + today date (only contains the year) + auto increment number (example: GRF20110001, NKO20110001) How can I do this workflow in SharePoint 2010?

Thank you for your help!

Cook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has nothing to do with workflow.  you should create a custom field: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx

jt